# How to convert the column names with Jsonlite in R without using melt

Tags: json, r

I have the following test matrix within R

```
a <- matrix(c(14,356,34,4),nrow = 2)
colnames(a) <- c("test1", "test2")
json.format <- toJSON(a)
r.format    <- fromJSON(json.format)
```

as you can see, at the beginning the matrix `a` had columnames. After converting to json and back, the matrix `r.format` lost the columnames. I know that the melting `a` before converting to json would give the desired result. For whatever reason, I cant use the melt function. Is there another way to perform this?

Comment: Is the reason you can't use the `melt` function that you haven't loaded the package it's in? `library(reshape2)`. That said, why not just convert to `data.frame`? `fromJSON(toJSON(as.data.frame(a)))` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

jsonlite doesn't like to preserve dimension names for matrices apparently. Is there a reason you're not storing it as a data.frame? You can convert it there and back with

```
json.format <- toJSON(as.data.frame(a))
r.format    <- as.matrix(fromJSON(json.format))
```

Or you could use the `RJSONIO::toJSON` function instead of jsonlite's

```
json.format <- RJSONIO::toJSON(a)
r.format    <- fromJSON(json.format)
```

but it still returns a data.frame by default.